# ADF Range Paging : Query executed for each page on first page load

Tags: listview, iterator, range, oracle-adf, rownum

I have a use case in which I want my ADF view object query to be executed only for first 10 records on the page load. And then run the query for other records on clicking on more items.

I have implemented following for this:

-- Application Module level:

```
<ViewUsage
    Name='MyVO'
    FetchSize=11>
```

-- View Object level:

```
   - PageIterMode="Full"
   - UseGlueCode="false"
   - FetchMode="FETCH_AS_NEEDED"
   - FetchSize="11"
   - RangeSize="10"
   - AccessMode="RANGE_PAGING"
```

-- JSFF Page Def level:

```
<iterator binds="MyVO" RangeSize="10" RowCountThreshold="-1">
```

-- JSFF Page level:

```
<af:listView value="#{bindings.MyVO.collectionModel}"
                         var="row" selection="none"
                         styleClass="AFStretchWidth border-top-grey" rows="10"
                         groupDisclosurePolicy="initiallyExpanded"
                         selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.MyVO.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                         selectionListener="#{bindings.MyVO.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                         emptyText="#{bindings.MyVO.viewable ? applcoreBundle.TABLE_EMPTY_TEXT_NO_ROWS_YET : applcoreBundle.TABLE_EMPTY_TEXT_ACCESS_DENIED}"
                         fetchSize="#{bindings.MyVO.rangeSize}"
                         id="lv1">
```

Issue Description:

1. When loading the jsff page from a task flow, I can see from logs that the query is being generated as expected with following where clause:

"
    ) IQ  WHERE ROWNUM < :Bind_RangePage_High) WHERE Z_R_N > :Bind_RangePage_Low
"

And the bind variable being set to: “rownum query between (0, 13)”

2. But apart from the above bind variables, the page also tries to query for other pages too such as following:

   - “rownum query between (10, 23)”
   - “rownum query between (20, 33)”
   - …
   - “rownum query between (190, 203)”

Can somebody please help if am missing any configuration here ?
I want just one query to be run here, otherwise my page load takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect in UI the number of rows on first load being displayed is 13 rows.

From listView documentation it says

> This component can be stretched by a parent layout component that stretches its children, e.g. panelStretchLayout, panelSplitter. In such a scenario, it will show scrollbars so that the content can be scrolled.

<strike>On other note have you tried [fetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E12419_09/tagdoc/af_listView.html)</strike>

> "fetchSize" is the number of rows requested from the client to the server on each attempt to fill the component.

Comment: Hi Amit, the number of rows being displayed are same as the Range Size,i.e., 10 as per my requirement. But the problem is even though only 10 rows are displayed on first load, it runs the query in backend for each page in batches of 13 each.

Comment: 1) set your vo fetchSize=13 and 2) Page Def iterator rangeSize = 13. Lets give it a shot to see if that helps.